# Rails sorting multiple models on the same datatype "period_end" as datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

So far I have this for the sorting

```
sets = Array.new
sets += current_user.experiences.period_end + current_user.educations.period_end
sets.sort! do |current_user.experiences, current_user.educations| 
  current_user.experiences.period_end <==> current_user.educations.period_end
end
```

with this for the models

```
class Experience < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessible :period_end

...
class EducationExperience < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessible :period_end
...
```

And in the display on HTML I'd like to make an if statement to see if it's an experience or an education experience to change the color of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make if statements, just set proper class name to each container respectively. For example (using Slim):

```
div(class="#{model_name.class.to_s.underscore}")
 = model_name.desired_property
```

Your div will have class `experience` or `education_experience` respectively and you can adjust styles for them. Cheers

Comment: but how do i get both models in the same sort?

Comment: What is wrong with simple `sets.sort_by { |experience| experience.period_end }` or `sets.sort_by { |experience| experience.period_end }.reverse!` if you need descending order

Comment: because i need both experience and education_experience showing in the order of period end

Comment: You want an array where first part is list of experiences sorted by `period_end` value and second part list of `education_experience` sorted by `period_end` value also?

Comment: try this `sets.sort_by { |experience| experience.period_end }`